# Techniques to Authenticate Web Server to C# Application

Tags: c#, xml, security

I have a C# program that fetches XML from my server to display news, show update alerts, and control parts of the program behavior. What techniques do I have at my disposal to ensure the program is connected to a REAL server?

Answer (score 0):

Ususally I use SOAP web services for similar tasks. To ensure only allowed clients can connect, I do use:

- Ensure only HTTPS connections are allowed.
- Have an API key (`string`) as an addition parameter to all web service methods.

By using the API key, the server can check a list of allowed API keys (e.g. stored in a database or simply a constant string) and reject non-allowed client requests with invalid API keys.

An example would be:

```
public class MyWebService : 
    WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetXml(string apiKey) 
    { 
        if( isApiKeyValid(apiKey) )
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();

            // TODO: generate XML document.

            return doc.OuterXml;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid API key.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `isApiKeyValid` function would contain the logic to check whether the passed API key is valid or invalid.